# htaccess www to non www does not work for sub directories

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following .htaccess code.

.htaccess in root folder

```
#for redirecting www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#temporary redirect root to dir/
RedirectMatch ^/$ /dir/
```

.htaccess in dir folder

```
RewriteEngine  on
#for changing index file to a custom one
DirectoryIndex abc.php?tag=ho

#for simple url
RewriteRule ^what/([^/]*)\.html$ /dir/abc.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

With current code www.domain.com redirects to domain.com but www.domain.com/dir/ does not redirect.

I need to amend two things:

1. Redirect www to non wwww
2. Redirect domain.com to domain.com/dir/

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Combining Redirect(match) and rewriterule is asking for trouble. Instead of your RedirectMatch use:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^dir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: +1 for recommending to avoid mixing mod_alias and mod_rewrite.